# Initialize instance of C++ class with custom constructer as Objective C class member?

Tags: c++, objective-c

Is there any way to do it

```
class A {
    int _v;
    A(int v) : _v(v) {}
};

@interface  B : NSObject {
    A a;
}
@end
```

except **A* a** or **std::unique_ptr a** ?

Comment: Would `A a(1)` work?

Comment: What error does it give you when you compile that?

Comment: Floris Velleman, nope :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, when you alloc an Objective-C class then the default constructor of all "C++ typed member variables" is called. Keeping the C++ class' instance at arms length with a pointer or unique_ptr and calling a constructor with arguments in the Objective-C init method is the usual way to handle this situation.